# Add item from array to another array where is same id

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json

Any way how to add current_value from **array2** to **array1** where is *same filter_id* ?

**array1**

```
const [productsFiltersSlider, setProductsFiltersSlider] = React.useState(undefined);

0: {id: '1', product_id: '28', filter_id: '26', type: 'slider', value: '60'}
1: {id: '2', product_id: '28', filter_id: '25', type: 'slider', value: '5'}
length: 2
```

**array2**

```
const [filteredValuesSlider, setFilteredValuesSlider] = React.useState([{current_value:'', filter_id:''}]);

0: {current_value: '12', filter_id: '25'}
1: {current_value: '63', filter_id: '26'}
length: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below:

```js
const productsFiltersSlider = [{ id: '1', product_id: '28', filter_id: '26', type: 'slider', value: '60' }, { id: '2', product_id: '28', filter_id: '25', type: 'slider', value: '5' } ] 
const filteredValuesSlider = [{ current_value: '12', filter_id: '25' }, { current_value: '63', filter_id: '26' } ]

filteredValuesSlider.forEach(({
  filter_id,
  current_value
}) => {
  const matchedItem = productsFiltersSlider.find((item) => item.filter_id === filter_id);
  matchedItem.current_value = current_value;
})

console.log(productsFiltersSlider);
```

Since you are using react and you might need to re-render it. Then, do like this:

```
setProductsFiltersSlider((prevProductsFiltersSlider) => {
  const updatedProductsFiltersSlider = [...prevProductsFiltersSlider];
  filteredValuesSlider.forEach(({ filter_id, current_value }) => {
    const matchedItem = updatedProductsFiltersSlider.find(
      (item) => item.filter_id === filter_id
    );
    matchedItem.current_value = current_value;
  });
  return updatedProductsFiltersSlider;
});
```

Comment: In first of thank you for your time. When I run code snipper here its working fine, but when I insert code and trying to console.log I am getting default filteredValuesSlider

Comment: So problem fixed, thank you for your response and for your time, you helped me lots of.